# Custom scrollbar style with DHTMLX gantt

Tags: jquery, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

I'm using DHTMLX gantt. It's very OK but there is a problem. I want to custom its scrollbar style for better view but it's not successful. I used some plugins to style its scrollbar but it's not working. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide some code or demo so we could check what the problem is

Comment: Well, now horizontal scroll starts from the left corner of the chart. But I want it starts from the left corner of the gantt tasks(gantt_task div). How can I do that? I can't find any config to do this.

Comment: You need to limit max width of scrollbar element and push it to the right side of a chart.
Here is how it can be done with static sizes 
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/snippet/32d02047
However in real app you'll probably need to set width dynamically based on with of timeline section